# CSS image linear-gradient cover image

Tags: css, linear-gradients

```
background-image: url('http://unsplash.it/1200x800'), linear-gradient(red, transparent);    
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right;
```

I use the above code to display a background image on the right side that is contained and to fill the left space by linear-gradient from red to the image's transparency. This doesn't work though as it displays the image on the right side but on the left just a linear-gradient from red to transparent that doesn't go over the image... How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just flip the gradient and the image order around. Gradient first, then the image.

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, transparent), url('http://unsplash.it/1200x800');    
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to have the red start at the left side and slowly transition to transparent on the right side of the screen, just add "to right," in the gradient before "red, transparent"

```
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, transparent), url('http://unsplash.it/1200x800');    
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

div {
  height: 300px;
}

<div></div>
```